# recursively fill a sql table based on data in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am working with a schedule table where the an office has appointments in the morning, then blocked off during lunch and then more appointments in the afternoon. this office is looking for the ability to change its frequency and quantity of appointments on the fly based on start and end times it already has.

for example: if the office has an appointment *every 60 minutes* from 10 - 12 lunch from 12-1 and afternoon appointments from 1-3 then the schedule table would look like this

```
Day         Time                IsBlocked   EndTime
2013-07-01  10:00:00.0000000    0           NULL
2013-07-01  11:00:00.0000000    0           NULL
2013-07-01  12:00:00.0000000    1           13:00:00.0000000
2013-07-01  13:00:00.0000000    0           NULL
2013-07-01  14:00:00.0000000    0           NULL
```

lets say they want to change that days appointments to *2 appointments* every half hour *(30 minutes)*
they could call a stored proc

`ChangeAppointmentFrequency(@day = '7/1/2013', @intervalInMinutes = 30, @numberOfAppointmentsInTheInterval = 2)`

it would insert the NEW appointments where in the new slots and leave any existing appointment untouched.

```
  Day           Time      IsBlocked EndTime
2013-07-01  10:00:00.0000000    0   NULL
2013-07-01  10:00:00.0000000    0   NULL
2013-07-01  10:30:00.0000000    0   NULL
2013-07-01  10:30:00.0000000    0   NULL
2013-07-01  11:00:00.0000000    0   NULL
2013-07-01  11:00:00.0000000    0   NULL
2013-07-01  11:30:00.0000000    0   NULL
2013-07-01  11:30:00.0000000    0   NULL
2013-07-01  12:00:00.0000000    1   13:00:00.0000000
2013-07-01  13:00:00.0000000    0   NULL
2013-07-01  13:00:00.0000000    0   NULL
2013-07-01  13:30:00.0000000    0   NULL
2013-07-01  13:30:00.0000000    0   NULL
2013-07-01  14:00:00.0000000    0   NULL
2013-07-01  14:00:00.0000000    0   NULL
2013-07-01  14:30:00.0000000    0   NULL
2013-07-01  14:30:00.0000000    0   NULL
```

I am having a hard time finding the start and end date eloquently with out using cursors 
thanks

initial table

```
CREATE TABLE Schedule([Day] DATE,[Time] TIME, IsBlocked bit, EndTime TIME);
insert into Schedule ([Day], [Time], IsBlocked, EndTime) values 
('7/1/2013', '10:00:00', 0, null),
('7/1/2013', '11:00:00', 0, null),
('7/1/2013', '12:00:00', 1, '13:00:00'),
('7/1/2013', '13:00:00', 0, null),
('7/1/2013', '14:00:00', 0, null)
```

Comment: Why is in the result table every row doubled except the blocked one?

Comment: the blocked row represents the office lunch hour. where they do not take appointments

Comment: The question was why your result has two rows with `10:00:00`, `10:30:00` and so on?

Comment: 2 rows because the number of appointments went from 1 every hour to 2 every half hour.

Comment: Can you provide a sample output?

Comment: You say "an" appointment every 60 minutes.  Do I understand correctly that there is no double-booking and no overlap, that is, one and only one appointment can occupy the time-slot in whole or in part? Or can appointments overlap? Can a 30-minute appointment begin at 10:45 if there's already an hourly appointment at 11:00? Please elaborate on "untouched".

Comment: The length of the appointment is not specified just the start time. The office can choose to change the number of appointments in the interval. In the above example the office went from 1 appointment in the time interval to 2

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't follow the answer. What is "the interval"?

Comment: The interval is the length of time between appointments. If I were to say "this office accepts 2 appointments every 30 minutes  " 30 is the interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to complete this using a CTE for the AMtimes and PMTimes

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.procedures WHERE Name = 'InsertAppointmentDay' AND [type_desc] = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE')
    DROP PROCEDURE InsertAppointmentDay;
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertAppointmentDay]
    @BACCode char(6)  
    ,@Division varchar(10)
    ,@ScheduleDate date
    ,@StartTime1 time(7)
    ,@EndTime1 time(7)
    ,@StartTime2 time(7)
    ,@EndTime2 time(7)   
    ,@TimeZoneAbbreviation char(6)   
AS
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @IntervalMinutes INT 
    DECLARE @AppointmentsPerInterval INT 
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) ;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT  ;

    -- make sure the dealer does not already have records in the schedule table for that day. We want to make sure if you already have appointments for that day 
    if   exists  (select Id from Schedule where   DealerDivision = @Division and DealerBACCode = @BACCode and AppointmentDay = @ScheduleDate)
    begin
        set @ErrorMessage = 'a record already exist in schedule table with DealerDivision = '+@Division+' and DealerBACCode = '+@BACCode+' and AppointmentDay = '+CAST(@ScheduleDate as varchar(20)); 
        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,  16,  @ErrorState );
        Return;
    end 

    BEGIN TRY 
        BEGIN TRANSACTION 
            DECLARE @ZipOffset char(6);

            SELECT @ZipOffset = [TimeZoneOffset]  FROM [TimeZone]   WHERE [TimeZoneAbbreviation] = @TimeZoneAbbreviation;

            -- find out from the frequency table how many minutes are in the interval and how many appointments per interval. look it up by FrequencyCode in the Frequency table 
            select @IntervalMinutes = IntervalMinutes, @AppointmentsPerInterval= AppointmentsPerInterval 
                from   Frequency where Code = (select top 1 AppointmentCode from Dealer where  Division = @Division and BACCode = @BACCode) 


            -- @Intervals table is a temp table with all the possiable timeslots we will add (a morning section and an afternoon section)
            -- example. if the location is open from 10:00 to 11:00 lunch then 13:00 to 15:00 the and the interval is 60 minutes you will get
            -- 10:00   
            -- 11:00 
            -- 13:00
            -- 14:00
            -- 15:00 
            DECLARE @Intervals table    (   [Time] TIME   UNIQUE ([Time])) 

            if (@StartTime2 is null)
            begin
                ;WITH AmSlots([TimeSlot] ) AS 
                ( 
                        SELECT @StartTime1   UNION ALL 
                        SELECT 
                        [TimeSlot] = DATEADD(mi, @IntervalMinutes, [TimeSlot]) 
                        FROM AmSlots WHERE DATEADD(mi, @IntervalMinutes, [TimeSlot]) <=  @EndTime1
                ) 
                insert into @Intervals select [TimeSlot] from [AmSlots]  
            end
            else 
            begin
                print 'pm times'
                ;WITH AmSlots([TimeSlot] ) AS 
                ( 
                        SELECT @StartTime1   UNION ALL 
                        SELECT 
                        [TimeSlot] = DATEADD(mi, @IntervalMinutes, [TimeSlot]) 
                        FROM AmSlots WHERE DATEADD(mi, @IntervalMinutes, [TimeSlot]) <=  @EndTime1
                ) ,PmSlots([TimeSlot] ) AS 
                (  
                        SELECT @StartTime2    UNION ALL
                        SELECT 
                        [TimeSlot] = DATEADD(mi, @IntervalMinutes, [TimeSlot])  
                        FROM PmSlots WHERE DATEADD(mi, @IntervalMinutes, [TimeSlot]) <=  @EndTime2  
                ) 
                insert into @Intervals select [TimeSlot] from [AmSlots] union all select [TimeSlot] from [PmSlots] 
            end


            -- @DayAppointments is a table to store the combination of time slots with the Number of appointments per interval
            -- example if the location is open from 10:00 to 11:00 lunch then 13:00 to 14:00 the and the interval = 60 minutes and the AppointmentsPerInterval = 3 you will get
            -- 1 | 10:00   
            -- 2 | 10:00   
            -- 3 | 10:00   
            -- 1 | 11:00   
            -- 2 | 11:00   
            -- 3 | 11:00   
            -- 1 | 13:00   
            -- 2 | 13:00   
            -- 3 | 13:00   
            -- 1 | 14:00   
            -- 2 | 14:00   
            -- 3 | 14:00   
            DECLARE @DayAppointments TABLE 
            (
                [AppointmentNumberForTimeSlot] INT,
                [Time] TIME
                UNIQUE ([AppointmentNumberForTimeSlot],[Time])
            )
            -- Quanity is a sequence table (if @AppointmentsPerInterval = 3   Quanity will contain  1, 2, 3) used to cross join with @Intervals to get the @DayAppointments
            ;WITH Quanity([AppointmentNumberForTimeSlot] ) AS
            (
                    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                    SELECT  [AppointmentNumberForTimeSlot] = [AppointmentNumberForTimeSlot] + 1  FROM Quanity WHERE [AppointmentNumberForTimeSlot]  <   @AppointmentsPerInterval
            ) 
            insert into @DayAppointments select [AppointmentNumberForTimeSlot], [Time] from Quanity cross join @Intervals 

            --select * from  @DayAppointments   

            -- insert one record into Schedule for each record in @DayAppointments 
            INSERT INTO [Schedule]  ([DealerBACCode],[DealerDivision],[AppointmentDay],[AppointmentTime], [ZipOffset], [TimeZoneAbbreviation], [ModifiedBy])
                select  @BACCode , @Division ,@ScheduleDate ,[Time]  , @ZipOffset , @TimeZoneAbbreviation , 'InsertAppointmentDay' from  @DayAppointments  where [Time] IS NOT NULL 
            print 'about to compelte transaction'
         COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
        print 'about to Rollback transaction'
        Rollback Transaction  
        set @ErrorMessage  = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        set @ErrorState   = ERROR_STATE() 
        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 16, @ErrorState);
        Return;
    END CATCH;  
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your answer is that appointments cannot overlap, I would approach the problem like this.

Create a CTE with a starting and ending time for every slot in the work-day, according to your (new) definition of slot-duration, and according to the time the office opens in the morning (and closes, of course).

Then insert from that CTE into your existing appointments table where not exists any appointment (or lunch slot) whose start time or end time would fall between your CTE slot's start-time and end-time.

P.S. You  have to calculate the endtime when only an appointment duration is given/defined.  The start-time is based on the office's opening time.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is not clear, but I'm not sure there is a solution given your design.

There is no primary key in your appointment table, which immediately throws up warning flags. From a practical standpoint, you have no way to know which records to pair. What if the parallel appointment start times are offset from each other?

For example, suppose one set of appointments starts on the hour and half-hour, the other set starts on the 1/4 and 3/4 hours. There is nothing in your model to show that. It could just as easily be interpreted as one series of 15 minute appointments starting on each 1/4 hour.

If you want parallel distinct tracks, then you need some kind of identifier to distinguish the tracks. The track ID could represent a meeting room, or host, or something more abstract.

I also would recommend having both a start and stop time in each appointment row. Why would you want to assume there is no gap between the end of one appointment and the start of the next?